# Location.subscribe()がリークしてしまう

Tags: angular2, angular4

ブラウザのBackボタンが押されたことを検知するためにLocationクラスを使用しています。
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html

```
export class PathLocationComponent {
  location: Location;
  constructor(location: Location) { 
     location.subscribe(val => console.log(val))//output popstate
  }
}
```

しかしながらこのコードで「戻る」と「進む」を繰り返すと出力されるログの数が増えて行ってしまいます。
Location.subscribe()がリークしているものと思われますが、Location.unsubscribe()がないので解放の仕方もわかりません。

リークを防ぐ方法もしくは、subscribeを解放する方法はありますでしょうか。

---

PlatformLocation.onPopState().というメソッドもありますが
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PlatformLocation-class.html

ドキュメントで以下の様に言われてしまっています。

```
This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location.
```

Comment: in SOen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451244/location-subscribe-is-leaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOen側で回答頂きました。

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class PathLocationComponent implements OnDestroy {
location: Location;
private subscription: Subscription;

      constructor(location: Location) {
        this.subscription = <Subscription>location.subscribe(val => console.log(val))//output popstate
      }

     ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
     }
}
```